# why does python remove function affecting class instance

Tags: python, list, class

I'm running this code with the following output but I don't want the .remove() to affect the class instance.

```
class dumby:
    def __init__(self):
        a = []


test1 = dumby()
A = [1,1]
test1.a = A
print(test1.a)
A.remove(A[0])
print(test1.a)
```

Output

```
[1, 1]
[1]
```

The output I want is

```
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
```

Please help!

Comment: Python doesn't make the implicit copies you're expecting. [Objects and variables don't interact like that in Python.](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: You could take a slice of the array to make a copy:`test1.a = A[:]`

Comment: I really like this article, https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/. It's about functions but the same reasoning applies to assignment of instance attributes.

Comment: BTW, `a = []` in the `__init__` method achieves nothing. It creates a local variable named `a` and throws it away at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python variables (or member attributes) actually hold *references* to objects. Some object are immutables (numbers, strings), but most and specifically lists are. So when you modify a mutable object, all references to it are affected, whatever reference was used to change it.

That is exactly what has happend here:

```
test1 = dumby()  # ok, you create a new dumby
A = [1,1]        # ok you create a new list referenced by A
test1.a = A      # test1.a now references the same list
print(test1.a)
A.remove(A[0])   # the list is modified
print(test1.a)   # you can control that the list is modified through the other ref.
```

What you want to do is to assign a copy of the original list:

```
test1.a = A[:]   # test1.a receives a copy of A (an independent object)
```